# Importing Excel Data in database using VB.Net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I have a new Program in VB.Net, my Project request that Exports Data in Datagridview into an Excel File . After Exporting it, I will Edit the Excel File and import it into App.
my steps are:

First the user uploads the file then inset data from excel file to dataset
then covert data from dataset to datatable.
`for i = 0 to  "BookID" of column.rows.count-2` .

If have `BookID` in DataSet then update, else add new data

But now I have error when convert data dataset to datatable
the error mess :

> System.ArgumentException:オブジェクトはADODB.RecordSetまたはADODB.Recordではありません
> (This is Japanese. Sorry but I don't know how to exactly translate this in to English)

> System.ArgumentException: Object is not ADODB.RecordSet or ADODB.Record

How can I fix it. Here is my code in Import. thank you

````
        Dim conn As OleDbConnection
        Dim dta As OleDbDataAdapter
        Dim dts As DataSet
        Dim excel As String
        Dim openFileDialog As New OpenFileDialog
        Dim table As New DataTable


        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments
        openFileDialog.Filter = "All Files (*.*|*.*|Excel files (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|XLS Files (*.xls)|*xls)"

        If (openFileDialog.ShowDialog(Me) = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) Then
            Dim fi As New IO.FileInfo(openFileDialog.FileName)
            Dim fileName As String = openFileDialog.FileName

            excel = fi.FullName
            conn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + excel + ";Extended Properties=Excel 12.0;")
            dta = New OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [Sheet1$]", conn)
            dts = New DataSet
            dta.Fill(dts, "[Sheet1$]")
            dts.Tables.Add(table)
            conn.Close()
            ' add new data from excel file to SQL
            For i As Integer = 1 To table.Rows.Count - 2 Step +1
                sql = "SELECT * FROM `tblbooks` WHERE 1`BookID` = '" & table.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString() & "'"
                sqladd = "INSERT INTO `tblbooks`(`AccessionNo`, `BookTitle`, `BookDesc`, `Author`, `PublishDate`, `BookPublisher`, `CategoryId`, `BookPrice`, `BookQuantity`, `Status`, `BookType`, `DeweyDecimal`, `OverAllQty`, `Donate`, `Remark`) VALUES (@AccessionNo,@BookTitle,@BookDesc,@Author,@PublishDate,@BookPublisher,@CategoryId,@BookPrice,@BookQuantity,@Status,@BookType,@DeweyDecimal,@OverAllQty,@Donate,@Remark)"
                sqledit = "UPDATE `tblbooks` SET `AccessionNo`=@AccessionNo,`BookTitle`=@BookTitle',`BookDesc`=@BookDesc,`Author`=@Author,`PublishDate`=@PublishDate,`BookPublisher`=@BookPublisher,`CategoryId`=@CategoryId,`BookPrice`=@BookPrice,`BookQuantity`=@BookQuantity,`Status`=@Status,`BookType`=@BookType,`DeweyDecimal`=@DeweyDecimal,`OverAllQty`=@OverAllQty,`Donate`=@Donate,`Remark`=@Remark WHERE @BookID"
                save_or_update_excel(sql, sqladd, sqledit)
            Next
            sql = "SELECT * FROM `tblcategory`"
            reloadDtg(sql, dtgList)

        Else
            '----------------Start import to data base--------



        End If
    End Sub ```
````

Comment: It would be helpful to know exactly where that exception is occurring.  Guessing the issue is here dta.Fill(dts, "[Sheet1$]")?  if so, you might want to have a read over the docs for the fill method https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.common.dataadapter.fill?view=net-5.0

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it is help me so much. I have fixed that error  . (Smile)